# Enable drop-down lists in Google Sheets reading mode

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of flags classified in three filters (drop-down lists). The problem is that the drop-down list does not work in reading mode, only in editor mode. I just wanted people to see the lists and be able to interact. Is it possible to use this option in some way without having to be in editor mode?

Editor mode
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0tEc.jpg

Reading mode (link shared)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPG8i.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The implementation you are looking for is not possible using view only (Read only) permission on Google Sheets due to the fact that when someone makes changes to the selected cell via the dropdown menu, this will count as an "Edit".

A workaround I could suggest is to set the view to Edit and protect all cells on the sheet  with the exception of the cells with dropdown list (Data validation) and set the edit permission access to only yourself. Here's more information on how to protect an entire sheet or range/s of cells:

- [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cprotect-a-range-or-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

I 100% agree and have the same use case and others described. I want people to be able to use the drop-down menu and select options from it but NOT be able to edit the drop-down values and NOT be able to remove the drop-down alltogether by editing the cell or deleting its values or validation.

This seems like a pretty basic request with lots of use cases from lots of types of users. Hopefully Google sees these notes, otherwise, I might send them a separate note on their board.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have this same problem and I'm growing frustrated. How in the world such simple blunder could escape the creators of Google Sheets? Obviously, if someone creates a spreadsheet with drop-downs in a range of cells, and said spreadsheet is to be shared with other users who will be granted limited edit permissions for certain parts of the spreadsheet, it is more than obvious that the creator of the spreadsheet wants his or her users to see and make use of the drop-downs, BUT also wants to make sure that nobody will accidentally delete the data validation contained in the cells (in other words, the drop-down itself). This is so obvious. I don't understand why Google Sheets hasn't yet come up with an extra permission (or a special 'edit' permission) where users can see and interact with a drop-down while in edit, but without the ability of deleting or accidentally changing the cell validation in any way. It would be like, you see it and you can interact, but you can't delete it or change the validation. Simple and nothing but common sense. Come on Google Sheets... let's get to it, please. It shouldn't be too hard to enable such partial edit permissions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).