# Prevent google sheet users without permission to edit drop down options, but select them

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, dropdown

This is my use case. I want anyone with or without a Google login to

1. See the sheet
2. Interact with drop downs on some cells

We can easily achieve this but locking the sheet (with permissions) and adding exceptions to the cell with drop downs. Also, we can set 'reject input' to prevent users from typing random stuff into those cells. But the issue is in this way they can go to the drop-down edit section to change the drop-down options.

What I want is for users to be able to select the values from the drop-down but prevent them from editing the dropdown options.

Is there any way to do this?

PS: I'll add some details on this locking the sheet

If you wanna lock some range of cells or an entire sheet you can do this by going to

'right-click any cell->view more cell options->protect range'

and setting writing permission 'only you'
(for a range of cells or entire sheet up to you)

There is an option to exclude some cells when locking the entire sheet.

There is another option in the drop-down edit window (unrelated to this permission thing) to reject random inputs. So others cannot just type random stuff into it.

So now the entire sheet is only editable by 'you' except the cells you excluded. Those are also restricted to prevent random inputs (from the drop-down edit view). But with all the restrictions others still can edit the drop-down options instead of just changing the value.

See the image, this is a user without login and he can see the edit button, and he can go into it and change drop-down options. I just wanna see that edit button gone (except for me).

[image]

Comment: Can you explain thoroughly this line; `We can easily achieve this but locking the sheet (with permissions) and adding exceptions to the cell with drop downs. Also, we can set 'reject input' to prevent users from typing random stuff into those cells.`,  Btw, have you seen this?[Enable drop-down lists in Google Sheets reading mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66737689/enable-drop-down-lists-in-google-sheets-reading-mode)

Comment: If you wanna lock some range of cells or an entire sheet you can do this by going to 'right click any cell->view more cell options->protect range' and setting writing permission 'only you'. There is an option to exclude some cells when doing that. So the entire sheet is only editable by you and some cells are editable by others(in my case everyone). So those cells that I excluded from the permission lock are fully editable. That means changing dropdown options to whatever they like and saving it for all.

Answer (score 1):

#### SUGGESTION

---

Unfortunately this is not possible without the use of Apps script, but I would suggest that you can change the `Dropdown` to `Dropdown(from a range)` referenced from another sheet, with that you can `hide and protect` that sheet somehow adding some restrictions with your users compared to a dropdown where they can easily add and change the values directly.

On the other hand using Apps Script, you can check this video:
[Prevent editors from modifying a dropdown list in Google Sheets with Apps Script](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQIq99L8MXE)

*Please note: that I am not affiliated nor the owner of the youtube video.*